# Regex lookahead with unknown number of spaces

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture a string that can contain any character but must always be followed by ';'
I want to capture it and trim the white space around it. I've tried using positive lookahead but that does not seem to exclude the whitespace.
Example:

```
this is a match   ;
this is not a match
```

regex:

`.+(?=\s*;)`

result:

`"this is a match   "` gets captured with trailing white space behind.

expected result:

`"this is a match"` (without whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match

```
.*(?<!\s)(?=\s*;)
```

provided the regex engine supports negative lookbehinds.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/73ApQZ/1)

Note that this returns an empty string if the string is `"  ;"`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure the first and the last characters of your match are not spaces. Thus we use the non-whitespace character match (`\S`) before and after the all character match (`.*`). As spaces might be optional, the any character match (`.`) must be optional, thus we use `*` instead of `+`.

```
\S.*\S(?=\s*;)
```

If the string can start with space use `.*\S(?=\s*;)`.

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/hOvB3W/1)

Thanks to @CarySwoveland for improving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the dot non greedy and start the match with a non whitespace character:

```
\S.*?(?=\s*;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iSTLYQ/1)

If the non whitespace character itself should also not be a semicolon:

```
[^\s;].*?(?=\s*;)
```